# Showing dynamic link previews in Slack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, frontend

We are a saas company. We provide custom domains to our clients when they use our dashboard product (say "Razrpy").
Eg: https://client1.razrpy.com, https://client2.razrpy.com

We use React and webpack.

Now, when someone shares this url say "https://client1.razrpy.com"
in Slack, they see a link preview. In this preview, the title tag value is displayed as "Razrpy" since in my index.html "Razrpy" is the value of title tag.

But lets say, I want to display a dynamic title like **"Client1-razrpy"** (i.e. subdomain+our product name) in the link preview, how can I do it?